# Azure FTP & WCF endpoints added but no access?

Tags: wcf, azure, ftp

I have setup a test VM and I am trying to get FTP via FileZilla working and connect an IIS website to an external WCF service. Neither are working, I have tried disabling the windows firewall to rule that out as well.

I have setup endpoints as below.
[Incoming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30FM1.png)
[Outgoing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMvEQ.png)

Comment: It is not very clear - you set up the FTP in the VM and try to connect to it using FileZilla from the external location, or vice versa?

Comment: Sorry yes, i have setup Filezilla Server and the server roles required for WCF, its actually the same setup i have on my live servers which are not running Azure, hence why i am thinking its the endpoints causing this.

Comment: I added the answer for FTP. I think it can be used for WCF service - please check if that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

i have just set up the FileZilla server on Azure VM.

That is what i did:

1) Install FileZilla with default settings

2) Set up the passive ports range. In my case it is 60000-60000.

3) Created outbound/inbound exceptions in firewall to allow "FileZilla Server.exe"

4) Using Powershell (i think that can be a problem, because there are some nuances when you create it on Azure portal):

```
Add-AzureAcccount
Get-AzureVM -Servicename "myvmcs"-Name VM1 | Add-AzureEndpoint -Name FTP-   Dynamic-60000 -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 60000 -PublicPort 60000 | Update-AzureVM
```

5) In FileZilla server settings, i have added user, shared folder and in Passive mode settings i set "Use the following IP" into the *domain name* of the VM.

Tried to connect it using a few different clients, and it works.